# Drop in r2 score when trying out Xgboost in different versions of python

Tags: python, regression, python-3.6, xgboost, python-3.10

I have been trying to run `xgboost` model on the same training data in different versions of python.
One version is python `3.6` and the other is python `3.10`.
But in both the model I can see a significant drop in R2 score.

- In python 3.6 - `0.33` r2 score
- In python 3.10 - `0.075` r2 score.

What could be the potential reason for this difference given we use the same training data.

Thanks in advance.

the same training data, generated a pickle file in both versions and did scoring.

Comment: Did you fix the random see to make sure you're actually training the 'same' model?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.